# How to set a cookie in Angular Universal?

Tags: angular, cookies, angular-universal

In our Angular 4.x project we use Angular Universal in combination with [angular2-cookie-law](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-cookie-law). I am aware of the fact that Angular Universal does not work with `window`, `document` etc, but I've read about some work-arounds. I tried the following:

```
if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
    this.showCookieLaw = true;
}
```

And wrap my cookie-law component in the view like this:

```
<cookie-law *ngIf="showCookieLaw">...</cookie-law>
```

However, this did not work and so far haven't found a different approach. Anyone can guide me the right direction?

Comment: What does 'did not work' mean?

Comment: When I run my project, as in - start the NodeJS server, I get the error `document is not defined`. Meaning, the pre-renderer does not understand the `document` element which is an issue with using Angular Universal.

Comment: The question should state this explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If a module used separate provider as an abstraction over `document.cookie`, it could be defined separately for server. However, it uses `document` global directly, so the provider that is responsible for that should be mocked in server module.

Considering that [the component uses service's `seen` public method](https://github.com/andreasonny83/angular2-cookie-law/blob/v1.3.1/src/cookie-law.component.ts#L71), this is the one that should be stubbed, something like:

```
import { CookieLawService } from 'angular2-cookie-law';

exports class MockedCookieLawService {
  seen = () => false;
}

...
imports: [CookieLawModule, ...],
providers: [{ provide: CookieLawService, useClass: MockedCookieLawService }, ...]
...
```

Comment: I wasn't able to work out your solution, therefore I continued searching for a different approach. After some time the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44402938/1164012) came by and help me out.

Comment: It wasn't obvious what your project structure looks like. 'should be mocked in server module' referred to the thing that is explained in that answer.