# Using animations in angular universal

Tags: angular, animation, universal

I am trying to use animations in universal mode. I followed the following link.

[Need BrowserAnimationsModule in Angular but gives error in Universal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330537/need-browseranimationsmodule-in-angular-but-gives-error-in-universal.)

1. Remove any reference to BrowserAnimationsModule from app.module.ts
   and create a separate app.browser.module.ts file.
2. Import NoopAnimationsModule to your app.server.module.ts so you
   don't throw errors in Node.
3. Modify your main.ts file to bootstrap AppBrowserModule instead of
   AppModule

the programs compiles successfully but when I run 'node server.js' command and try to open the page that uses animations, the server does not return anything and get the error of the page is not working.

Comment: I’m the person who posted that solution. It worked as of 6.0.3 but I just started a new project in 6.1.9 and it doesn’t work anymore. I’ll update if I find a solution.