# Angular Universal, How to isolate module with declarations from server-side execution?

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular-module, server-side-rendering, angular-dependency-injection

I have installed [ng2-pdf-viewer](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer) to show documents within angular 6 app.

To make it work I need to import PdfViewerModule in `FeatureModule` where I want to use `<ng2-pdf-viewer>` component.

The problem is in `PdfViewerModule`, it calls Element and Window object inside its functions and it crushes when serving `node server.js`.

At the moment my modules are imported like this:

```
BrowserModule > AppModule > FeatureModule > PdfViewerModule(declare <ng2-pdf-viewer>)
```

Usually I can solve such issues by importing such specific module directly into `BrowserModule` and supply `ServerModule` with some customly created mocked module which might declare samely named `<ng2-pdf-viewer>` mock.
The solution I thought about is to import `PdfViewerModule` in `BrowserModule` directly, like this:

```
BrowserModule(imports PdfViewerModule) > AppModule > FeatureModule
```

but in this case components of `FeatureModule` cant access `<ng2-pdf-viewer>` in their templates because it is not declared.

Is there a way to isolate `PdfViewerModule` from server-side execution, but keep its declarations?
Maybe there is absolutely diffrent approach fir such cases?

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick.

```
<ng2-pdf-viewer *ngIf="isBrowser"></ng2-pdf-viewer>

isBrowser: boolean;

constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: string) {
   this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
}
```

The `*ngIf` directive should prevent your PDF renderer to execute

**Edit:** that doesn't work because the browser javascript code executes even before the component initialization (in the module declaration)

As you already thought, you can try to adapt this solution [Need BrowserAnimationsModule in Angular but gives error in Universal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330537/need-browseranimationsmodule-in-angular-but-gives-error-in-universal) to your needs, you'd have an `AppBrowserModule` that imports `AppModule` plus another module that you'd create and that would wrap the `PdfViewerModule`, the components that use it and their associated routes.

Comment: same problem
`node server.js`
causes 
`webpack:///./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js?:1080`

`if (typeof Element.prototype.remove !== 'undefined') {`

Comment: The non-browser JS code from this module executes during the build or during execution?

Comment: during execution `ReferenceError: Element is not defined`

Comment: Ok so the problem comes from this line: https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer/blob/5f7237ed432cab08fda652810385434868017260/src/app/pdf-viewer/pdf-viewer.module.ts#L7 indeed you have no other choice than conditionnally import the module. And I don't know any way for doing that, except maybe lazy-loading but I'm not sure if it works on server side.