# Excluding module for server side rendering - Angular 8 Universal

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-universal, angular8

Hey im trying to explude the package `ngx-parallax` from server-side rendering since its causing errors.

Now I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330537/need-browseranimationsmodule-in-angular-but-gives-error-in-universal) and created a new `app.browser.module.ts` file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppModule} from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {ParallaxModule} from 'ngx-parallax';
// other browser exlusive imports

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // browser exlusive imports
    ParallaxModule,
    AppModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppBrowserModule { }
```

And im bootstrapping it in my main.ts file.

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import {AppBrowserModule} from './app/app.browser.module';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppBrowserModule)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
});
```

The ParallaxModule is now only included for the browser version but it appears not to be included at all. I keep getting the erro, that the used directive and config from the ParallaxModule is not included:

```
Can't bind to 'config' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("photos/196659/pexels-photo-196659.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260)"
     parallax [ERROR ->][config]="{ratio: 0.5}"> ...
```

But when I add the `ParallaxModule` to the app.module.ts file, it works like expected! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I converted it by usind ng add `@nestjs/ng-universal`

Comment: Can you show your AppModule as well? If the component that is using the directive is still declared in there as well it could be causing the issue.